# Better word for "critical mass"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests

> My thoughts began to shift from the political-science aspects of the idea to the computer-science aspects of it. This shift reached **critical mass** when I began learning how to program...

I don't think "critical mass" is the right word here. I'm looking for something like "turning point", analogous to the critical point on a graph, the top of a curve.

What's the word I'm looking for?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The phrase *[tipping point](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tipping_point)* sometimes is so used.  Its senses include  “(catastrophe theory) The point at which a slow, reversible change becomes irreversible, often with dramatic consequences” and “The point in time at which some new technology becomes mainstream”.

Also consider *[cusp](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cusp#Noun)*,  “(figuratively) An important moment when a decision is made that will determine future events”.

*Edit:* Also consider bib's worthwhile suggestion, *[turning point](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/turning_point#Noun)*: “A decisive point at which a significant change or historical event occurs, or at which a decision must be made.”

Comment: +1 Or possibly a *turning point*

Comment: The turning point is mentioned by OP himself, actually. I think what needs to be stated much more explicitly is that he must pick *exactly one* metaphor and then stick to it. The problem with the original sentence is not the metaphor chosen, but *the number* of metaphors chosen. Thoughts can shift, thoughts can reach a cricial mass, thoughts can get to a turning point. Pick one. But a shift does not have a turning point, a critical mass or a cusp. You already decided it's a shift.